# ASP MVC5 public readonly variable changes value when it should not

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, controller, action

For my application (which is used to manage some data for customers), I have a `public static class Util` where I store data that is used on a variety of places. In this class I have the following variable:

```
public static readonly List<string> PUBLICSALESMANAGERS = new List<string> { "aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd", "eeeee" };
```

This is a list of people that is the same in every case. Then, depending on the customer you're trying to manage, the sales manager for that customer needs to be added to the list.

In one of my controllers, I then have the following lines of code in some of the actions to do so:

```
List<string> salesManagers = Util.PUBLICSALESMANAGERS;
salesManagers.Insert(0, customer.SalesManager);
ViewBag.salesManagers = salesManagers;
```

For some reason, every time this code runs, the insert seems to be updating the `Util.PUBLICSALESMANAGERS` variable. Because of this, the list keeps getting longer on every request, which should not be the case.

Is there anyone who can help me with this?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

To avoid try and avoid confusion an example of how it SHOULD work:

When I load customer x, which has sales manager "sssss". My list should now look like: `"sssss", "aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd", "eeeee"`.

When I then load customer y, which has sales manager "mmmmm" I want my list to look like: `"mmmmm", "aaaaa", "bbbbb", "ccccc", "ddddd", "eeeee"`

And so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`List(T).Insert(Int32,T)` inserts an item at position specified by the first parameter. It doesn't overwrite. What you want is something like

```
  if (!salesManagers.Contains(customer.SalesManager))
    salesManagers.Insert(0, customer.SalesManager);
```

UPDATE: After clarification of the question, the way to go is to create a copy of the `Util.PUBLICSALESMANAGERS` list and modify that.

`new List(Util.PUBLICSALESMANAGERS)`

Comment: I know inserting doesn't overwrite. That's not what I'm trying to do. What I am trying to do is reuse the original list and adding the sales manager for that customer, only for the current action.

Comment: OK, I see. What about creating a copy via `new List(Util.PUBLICSALESMANAGERS)`

Comment: This helped! I should've been able to think of that...
Thanks a lot!